# Google Chrome does't load the "less.min.js" file

Tags: html, css, less

I wanted to start using less.js,but Google Chrome does't see it.
Everytime I open my code in Google Chrome,I have an error in console,that says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" about less.min.js.
So I'll be very glad,if you help me to solve this problem :)

I've even tried to write the main source from the http://lesscss.org/ in src,but it does't work,too.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Comment: Hey Gevorg, Have you followed these instructing? http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser -- I'm guessing Chrome can't find the file because you don't have a styles.less file in your root. Is the path to your file correct?

Comment: Hi. Yes,the path to my file is correct.I'm trying now the other ways written in the lesscss.org. 
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: "Yes,the path to my file is correct" — If it was the server wouldn't tell you it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` always indicates (as is self explanatory) that you are searching for your file in the wrong directory.

Are you running your website on a local server? If so, make sure that your HTML file and your `less` file are both in the server root folder.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072845/javascript-file-not-found).